# Need help in my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Last week a made a function for ellipsing the text inside some selector.

I was calling the function like this:

ellipsiText('.class',50) passing the selector and the max length of the text that i wanted to. This works fine, but im trying to make it a plugin, to call like this: $('.class').ellipsiText(50).

So, i was reading the tutorial in jquery website, and i understood how to do it. But i think i'm having an issue with the "this" seletor. Here is my original function:

```
function ellipsiText(selector,maxLength){


    var array = $(selector).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    var i;

    var teste = [];

    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){

        if (array[i].length > maxLength){

        teste.push(array[i].substr(0,maxLength) + "...");

        } else {

            teste.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var i=0;i<teste.length;i++){

    $(selector).each(function(i){

        $(this).text(teste[i]);

    });

    }


}
```

and here is my tentative of making a jquery plugin:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.ellipsiText = function(length){

        var array = $(this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();

        var i;
        var teste = [];

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (array[i] > length){
                teste.push(array[i].substr(0,length) + "...");
            } else {
                teste.push(array[i]);
            }
        }

        $(this).each(function(i){

            $(this).text(teste[i]);

        }); 
    };

}(jQuery));
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why so much looping? One each loop, check length, if > set Text. No need to map, loop, loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but the basic structure is something like this. Also you have so much looping in your code when one loop is needed.

```
$.fn.ellipsiText= function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({  //nice way to give to give defaults
        length : 50,
        ellipsi : "..."
        }, options );

    return this.each(function() {  //the return is needed for chaining
        var elem = $(this);
        var txt = elem.text();
        if (txt.length>settings.length) {
             elem.text(txt.substr(0,settings.length) + settings.ellipsi );
        }
    });

};
```

and call it

```
$( "div.defaults" ).ellipsiText();

$( "div.foo" ).ellipsiText({
    length : 10
});

$( "div.more" ).ellipsiText({
    length : 10,
    ellipsi : "<more>"    
});
```

Comment: This works! That is awesome... My code is just thousands of lines bigger

Comment: Even shorter: `text-overflow: ellipsis` ;)

Comment: epascarello, that is a way to subtract the size of the "ellipsi" setting in the total length of the text, since ellipsi is an object? I dont want to use text-overflow because i need to set a lot of things and this is not compatible with all browser at all

Comment: You mean `(settings.length - settings.ellipsi.length)`?

Comment: Yeah, didnt think it would work because the "length" variable

Answer (score 2):

Well first thing is not a problem, but instead of `$(this)` in the first function scope, you can use `this.map/this.each`.

The problem is, in the second code you do

```
if (array[i] > length)
```

instead of

```
if (array[i].length > length)
```

Nothing to do with the jQuery plugin!

http://jsfiddle.net/UY88r/

Comment: Oh i see he didn't copy over the code correctly. :)

Comment: LOL that was the problem!! Didnt see it... But taking a look in the other answers, i saw my code was bad, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a working function, just use it.

```
$.ellipsiText = ellipsiText;
$.fn.ellipsiText = function (count) {
    ellipsiText(this, count);
}
```

now you can use it like any of the following:

```
ellipsiText('.class',50);
$.ellipsiText('.class',50);
$('.class').ellipsiText(50);
```

There's no sense in rewriting the function you already have working when you can just use it.

Comment: Didnt thought about it. But i still want to know what i'm doing wrong on this, because if im going to make another one, i want to write it directly

Comment: At first glance, i don't see anything major wrong, however you are over-using `$()`. `this` is already a jquery object, so you can go straight to `this.map` for example rather than `$(this).map`